# Windows 8 apps not connecting to internet with USB dongle/modem

Tags: windows-8, internet, internet-connection, windows-store-app, usb-modem

The question pretty much says it all. I have Windows 8 Professional 64-bit and my main/only method of getting connected to the internet is to use this USB dongle/modem I have. Now it works perfectly, but when I go into the Windows "store" app it keeps on saying that I'm not connected to the web.

In fact this happens for all "apps", they all think I'm not connected to the web when I actually am. Normal desktop applications e.g. browsers run fine. Is this a bug that has **still** not been resolved or is there some setting I need to go mess with?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just upgraded to 8.1 and now nothing works. Says that I'm connected to the net but not even my browser (Chrome) wants to connect to the internet.